# How to add one inner join Instead of 3 inner joins

Tags: mysql, join

In here I'm trying to inner join SEARCHED_TAGS table and USER table. Here I use same join in three times. Not only this below I use this query many times. Is it cause to slow down the query & how can I write this query one time instead of 3 times.

Below you can see Query.

```
(
 select st.SEARCH_TEXT as SEARCH_TEXT
 from SEARCHED_TAGS st
 inner join USER usr
 on st.SEARCH_BY=usr.USER_ID
 where (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) and (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) and (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep)
 order by st.SEARCH_TIME desc
 limit 2
)
UNION
(
 select st.SEARCH_TEXT as SEARCH_TEXT
 from SEARCHED_TAGS st
 inner join USER usr
 on st.SEARCH_BY = usr.USER_ID
 where (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) and not (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) and (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep)
 order by st.SEARCH_TIME desc
 limit 2
)
UNION
(
 select st.SEARCH_TEXT as SEARCH_TEXT
 from SEARCHED_TAGS st
 inner join USER usr
 on st.SEARCH_BY= usr.USER_ID
 where (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) and not (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) and not (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep)
 order by st.SEARCH_TIME desc
 limit 2
)
```

Can I write like this instead of above.

```
inner join USER usr
on st.SEARCH_BY=usr.USER_ID
(
 select st.SEARCH_TEXT as SEARCH_TEXT
 from SEARCHED_TAGS st
 where (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) and (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) and (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep)
 order by st.SEARCH_TIME desc
 limit 2
)
UNION
(
 select st.SEARCH_TEXT as SEARCH_TEXT
 from SEARCHED_TAGS st
 where (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) and not (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) and (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep)
 order by st.SEARCH_TIME desc
 limit 2
)
UNION
(
 select st.SEARCH_TEXT as SEARCH_TEXT
 from SEARCHED_TAGS st
 where (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) and not (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) and not (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep)
 order by st.SEARCH_TIME desc
 limit 2
)
```

Thanks..

Comment: @philipxy The ugliness comes from the limit statements I think.

Comment: It would help if you said what you are trying to do in some other way than your queries, because it seems like your queries probably aren't doing it. Also please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the limit statements, this might be the best you can do with ordinary MySQL.  But using session variables we can do slightly better:

```
SELECT SEARCH_TEXT
FROM
(
    SELECT SEARCH_TEXT, grp,
        (@num:=if(@group = grp, @num +1, if(@group := grp, 1, 1))) row_number
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            st.SEARCH_TEXT as SEARCH_TEXT,
            st.SEARCH_TIME,
            CASE WHEN (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) AND (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) AND
                      (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep) THEN 1
                 WHEN (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) AND NOT (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) AND
                      (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep) THEN 2
                 WHEN (st.SEARCH_TEXT like :tagText) AND NOT (st.SEARCH_BY = :userId) AND NOT
                      (usr.DEP_ID = :userDep) THEN 3
                 ELSE 4 END AS grp
        FROM SEARCHED_TAGS st
        INNER JOIN USER usr
            ON st.SEARCH_BY = usr.USER_ID
    ) t1
    CROSS JOIN (select @num:=0, @group:=null) t2
    ORDER BY grp, t1.SEARCH_TIME DESC
) t
WHERE
    t.row_number <= 2 AND
    t.grp <= 3;
```

This code is untested, mainly because your query is too complex for easy testing, but I can iterate with you if you encounter any problems.